# Is there a way to limit the number of requests sent to browser for a long running process to 1 in a Flask Application?

Tags: flask

I am trying to make a web application out of a deep learning model which processes large files to output segmented files. Naturally, it takes approximately 30 minutes to process these files. I have noticed that before completing one task, it proceeds on to restart the process. I have read that this might be because if a webpage is unresponsive for long, the browser makes another request and therefore the application proceeds to start another run, while the previous one is still going on. Is there a way to limit this? Or is there a way to deal with time consuming process in Flask? Please mention exact details of how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Just start a thread to process the file in the background, and redirect the user to a loading page, that refreshes automatically:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os, uuid
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask, redirect, make_response
from time import sleep # For debugging

UPLOAD = './uploads'

if not os.path.isdir(UPLOAD):
    os.mkdir(UPLOAD)

def worker(Id):
    folder = os.path.join(UPLOAD, Id)
    sleep(10) # Processing the files
    with open(os.path.join(folder, 'isdone.txt'), 'wt') as o:
        o.write('yes')
        o.close()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return '''
<form action="/doit" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Do it!" />
</form>
'''

@app.route('/loading/<Id>', methods=['GET'])
def loading(Id):
    folder = os.path.join(UPLOAD, Id)
    if not os.path.isdir(folder):
        return 'Error: wrong Id'
    with open(os.path.join(folder, 'isdone.txt'), 'rt') as o:
        isdone = o.read().strip()
        o.close()
    if isdone == 'yes':
        return 'Done!'
    else:
        res = make_response('Loading...')
        res.headers['refresh'] = '3' # Refresh the page every 3 s
        return res

@app.route('/doit', methods=['POST'])
def doit():
    rnd = uuid.uuid4().hex
    folder = os.path.join(UPLOAD, rnd)
    os.mkdir(folder)
    with open(os.path.join(folder, 'isdone.txt'), 'wt') as o:
        o.write('no')
        o.close()
    # Upload the files...
    # Recomanded to create an anther subdirectory
    # on {folder}, to don't override the 'isdone.txt'
    Thread(target=worker, args=(rnd,)).start()
    return redirect(f'/loading/{rnd}')

app.run('0.0.0.0', 8080)
```